# Spring Integration - Spring example config namespace issue

Tags: spring, spring-integration

**Issue:** Getting namespace errors for elements in my spring config file.

"Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for element "int-ws:hyeader-enricher' of schema namcespace 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ws '

**Description:** Trying to create at the Spring Integration sample project from the spring website in a simple spring sts spring project using maven.

I didnt find this project in the sample directory for me to compare mine to.

[http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/](http://Spring%20IO%20-%20Spring%20Integration%20Example)

**Spring Bean Config File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-http="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http"
    xmlns:int-ws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ws"
    xmlns:int-xml="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http/spring-integration-http.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ws http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ws/spring-integration-ws.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml/spring-integration-xml.xsd">


<!-- Simple Service -->

<int:gateway id="simpleGateway"
    service-interface="foo.TempConverter"
    default-request-channel="simpleExpression" />

<int:service-activator id="expressionConverter"
    input-channel="simpleExpression"
    expression="(payload - 32) / 9 * 5"/>

<!-- Web Service -->

<int:gateway id="wsGateway" service-interface="foo.TempConverter"
    default-request-channel="viaWebService" />

<int:chain id="wsChain" input-channel="viaWebService">
    <int:transformer
       expression="'&lt;FahrenheitToCelsius xmlns=''http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/''&gt;&lt;Fahrenheit&gt;XXX&lt;/Fahrenheit&gt;&lt;/FahrenheitToCelsius&gt;'.replace('XXX', payload.toString())" />
    <int-ws:header-enricher>
        <int-ws:soap-action value="http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/FahrenheitToCelsius"/>
    </int-ws:header-enricher>
    <int-ws:outbound-gateway
        uri="http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx"/>
    <int-xml:xpath-transformer
        xpath-expression="/*[local-name()='FahrenheitToCelsiusResponse']/*[local-name()='FahrenheitToCelsiusResult']"/>
</int:chain>

</beans>
```

UPDATE - SOLUTION
I had to add the following dependencies not listed on there website. I added this to the POM file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-integration-ws</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>

</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-integration-xml</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring XML configuration namespaces need a namespace handler at runtime (the `META-INF/spring.handlers` class path resources, usually in JARs on the class path, nominate handler classes).

The reason that Spring is giving this message at runtime is because a namespace handler has not been registered for that XML element. The most likely reason is that the spring-integration-ws.jar (or perhaps a required dependency) is not on the class path at runtime.

Comment: This message comes up during the validation of the spring configuration xml. Not run time. I will check the spring integration samples directory for a spring.handlers file. However seems odd creating a new spring project in STS wouldnt create the necessary file.  I will also try doing the project in gradle vs maven. So like a lot of work just to get 1 example project working.

Comment: STS is probably validating against project dependencies. You don't create the `spring.handlers` file yourself: just put the right JARs on the class path. Check your `pom.xml` file has `spring-integration-ws` as a dependency (if you're using Maven).

Comment: As per the example on the Spring IO Integration website I just have spring-integration-core dependency for version 4.1.6 . I will try upload a screenshot of it.

Comment: Well, looking at the code in GitHub, the `http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ws` namespace requires `spring-integration-ws` as a dependency.

Comment: Ya your right. For some reason they left it out on the there website. Not sure why Spring would do that. I had to add to resolve the validation conflicts. Can you post the link to the project in github?

Comment: So looking at `basic/ws-*-gateway/pom.xml` in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples, these samples have the right dependencies.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-ws/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.handlers is the `spring.handlers` file in `spring-integration-ws.jar` that I mentioned - look at the nominated class to see the handlers registered for each element.